# Edge - new tab focus behavior

Tags: windows-10, browser-tabs, microsoft-edge

Is there a way to let Edge focus on the address bar once I open a new tab?

I experience the following behavior:

1. Open Edge
2. `Ctrl + t` (new tab)
3. Type e.g. `www.myfavouriteaddress.com`

**Issue**: The typing is ignored since the focus is not on the address bar.

Unfortunately I haven't found anything. [Microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/edge_other-edge_win10/no-focus-after-creating-a-new-tab/3ccdb04e-67ec-4a85-b168-6efaf52f83f5) didn't answer on that.

Right now I work around it like that:

1. Open Edge
2. `Ctrl + t` (new tab)
3. `Ctrl + l` (focus on address bar)
4. Type e.g. `www.myfavouriteaddress.com`

I'm looking for a setting which let me change the default `Ctrl + t` behavior. Any idea?

**Environment**

- Microsoft Edge 38.14393.2068.0
- Windows 10 Enterprise

---

**Update Feb. 7. 2019**

Checked my issue again with the Microsoft Edge browser in version:

- Microsoft Edge 41.16299.755.0
- Windows 10 Enterprise

The issue is gone.

Comment: I also have this issue but it is intermittent. Sometimes opening a new tab focuses the address bar, sometimes it doesn't. I haven't discerned a pattern yet.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to go to the settings on the browser and search for "tab". Then you will get the option to select where your search should be focused.

[image]

Don't forget to mark this as the correct answer or up vote if it helps you!

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could include the version of Edge you found this setting.